# Twitter iOS User Login

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication, oauth

I've implemented Twitter Login in my iOS app with the following tutorial:

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

But after I chose a Twitter account when I log in the first time, the app always defaults to this account.  I would like to enable users with multiple accounts to select the Twitter account they'd like to log into each time.

**How can I re-enable the UIActionSheet that allows the user to select which Twitter account they want to use for login?**

Comment: Have you tried to use `Twitter.sharedInstance.logOut`? Though it looks like call to this method is not enough (such questions on Twitter Developers forum are not resolved), but you also could try to clear cookies in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`

Comment: @std.denis thanks this worked for me!  if you create an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method `Twitter.sharedInstance.logOut` to delete the local Twitter user session. And you also should clear Twitter-related cookies in `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to prevent using of old credentials in further UIWebView-based login sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The new `Twitter Kit 3.0` now supports this flow by default. Every time that `login` is called, the user will be able to add or change their Twitter account.